# Data.Annotations with .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, data-annotations

I have a number of domain classes with DataAnnotations applied to them, and I require to validate them in my service layer.

I am using WCF, .NET 3.5

If i was using .NET 4 I would have access to the Validator as follows

```
Validator.ValidateObject(@event.Entity, new ValidationContext(@event.Entity, null, null), true);
```

is there a framework in 3.5 which allows me to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://annotationscontrib.codeplex.com/ with 3.5 be it with MVC.

If it doesn't work out of the box you can check the source code to see how the attributes are parsed.